# "list indices must be integers, not tuple"

Tags: python

When i run the following code, i get an error saying "list indices must be integers, not tuple".This error occours when i declare the variables first and second. Can anyone explain or fix this error

```
    globalViewDict = {'A': [('B', 6.5, 5001), ('F', 2.2, 5005), 'A', '2'], 
                  'B': [('A', 6.5, 5000), ('C', 1.1, 5002), ('D', 4.2, 5003), ('E', 3.2, 5004), 'B', '4'],
                  'C': [('B', 1.1, 5001), ('D', 1.6, 5003), 'C', '2'],
                  'D': [('F', 0.7, 5005), ('B', 4.2, 5001), ('C', 1.6, 5002), ('E', 2.9, 5004), 'D', '4'],
                  'E': [('B', 3.2, 5001), ('D', 0.7, 5003), ('F', 6.2, 5005), 'E', '3'],
                  'F': [('A', 2.2, 5000), ('D', 0.7, 5003), ('E', 6.2, 5004),'F','3']}

def dijkstrawPhase():
    global globalViewDict
    pprint.pprint(globalViewDict)
    #print "globalViewDict:", globalViewDict
    print""
    tempList =[]
    temptup = ()
    newList = []
    x=0

    for key,value in globalViewDict.iteritems():
        x=0
        i=0
        neighborsOfPacket = int(value[-1])
        while x < neighborsOfPacket:
            j=0
            id = str(value[i][0])
            cost = float(value[i][1])
            temptup =(key,id,cost)
            i = i + 1
            x = x + 1
            tempList.append(temptup)
    print "tempList\n",pprint.pprint(tempList)


    for x in tempList:
        first = tempList[x][0]
        second = tempList[x][1]
        j=0
        for j in tempList:
            if tempList[j][0]==second and tempList[j][i] == first:
                print "nothng dne"
            else:
                newList.append(tempList[x])
    print "newList\n",pprint.pprint(newList)

dijkstrawPhase()
```

Answer (score 3):

In the top `for` loop, you add some tuples to `tempList`.

```
 temptup =(key,id,cost)
 tempList.append(temptup)
```

In the bottom loop, you do:

```
for x in tempList:
    first = tempList[x][0]
    second = tempList[x][1]
```

`x` refers to the item in the list -- a tuple, not the index. What you want is more like this:

```
for x in tempList:
    first = x[0]
    second = x[1]
```